# replacing a database with pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am trying to replace an existing database with `pg_restore` and am running into issues. I apologize if this issue is elementary.

Specifically my Postgres install is set up like this:

- database `postgres` owned by `root`
- database `d` owned by `u`
- database `restore` owned by `u` (more on this later)

I created a dump like `pg_dump --format=custom ...`. I am now trying to replace `d` with the contents of that dump. Specifically I am running a command like `pg_restore -cC --dbname=$DB --exit-on-error --format=custom --username=$USER`.

But it seems no matter what combination of `$DB` and `$USER`, Postgres is unable to restore. From the error messages (below) Postgres seems to want the user to simultaneously be `root` and the owner of `d`. I have read the man pages and tried various combinations to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Specifically, if `$DB` is `d`, regardless of `$USER`, I get

> ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
>
> Command was: DROP DATABASE d;

Fair enough. So let's try `$DB=postgres` and `$USER=root`:

> ERROR:  must be owner of database d
>
> Command was: DROP DATABASE d;

Okay, so let's try `$DB=postgres` and `$USER=u`:

> ERROR:  must be member of role "root"
>
> Command was: ALTER DATABASE d OWNER TO root;

Huh? Maybe that has to do with logging into `postgres`, which is owned by `root`? Let's try `$DB=restore` (created specifically for this purpose) and `$USER=u`:

> ERROR:  must be member of role "root"
>
> Command was: ALTER DATABASE d OWNER TO root;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently, "root" is not a superuser (which is a bit odd, given the normal implications of the word "root").  The `pg_restore` command you wish to run must be run as a superuser.  Only a superuser can drop someone else's database, and then create a new database owned by someone else.

Although it looks like the restored database is going to be owned by "root", not "u".  I guess that is not what you are expecting, but it is what was encoded in the `pg_dump` output.

Comment: Yes you are right. I never would have thought `root` is not a super user. Thanks!